# How can I use skewnorm to produce a distribution with the specified skew?

Tags: scipy, statistics

I am trying to produce a random distribution where I control the mean, SD, skewness and kurtosis.

I can solve the mean and SD with some simple maths after the distribution is produced.

Kurtosis I am leaving on the shelf for the moment because it just seems too hard.

Skewness is today's problem.

```
import scipy.stats

def convert_to_alpha(s):
    d=(np.pi/2*((abs(s)**(2/3))/(abs(s)**(2/3)+((4-np.pi)/2)**(2/3))))**0.5 
    a=((d)/((1-d**2)**.5))
    return(a)

for skewness_expected in (.5, .9, 1.3):
    alpha = convert_to_alpha(skewness_expected)
    r = stats.skewnorm.rvs(alpha,size=10000)
    print('Skewness expected:',skewness_expected)
    print('Skewness obtained:',stats.skew(r))
    print()

Skewness expected: 0.5
Skewness obtained: 0.47851348006629035

Skewness expected: 0.9
Skewness obtained: 0.8917020428586827

Skewness expected: 1.3
Skewness obtained: (1.2794406116842627+0.01780402125888404j)
```

I understand that the calculated skewness will generally not match the desired skewness - this is a random distribution, after all. But I am confused as to how I can get a distribution with a skewness > 1 without falling into complex number territory. The rvs method appears incapable of handling it, since the parameter alpha is an imaginary number whenever skewness > 1.

How can I fix it so that I can generate distributions with skewness > 1, but not have complex numbers creeping in?

[With credit to [Warren Weckesser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1217358/warren-weckesser) for pointing me at Wikipedia in order to write the convert_to_alpha function.]

Answer (score 6):

Understand this thread is a year and a half old now, but I've run into this problem recently as well and it never seemed to get answered here. The further problem with converting between alpha from stats.skewnorm and the skewness statistic (excellent function to do that by the way) is that doing so will also alter the measures of central tendency for the distribution, which was problematic for my needs.

I've developed this based on the F-distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution). The end result of a lot of work is this function for which you specify the mean, SD and skewness required, and desired sample size. I can share the work behind it if anyone wishes. The output SD and skew become a little rough at extreme settings. Presumably because the F-distribution naturally sits around 1. It is also very problematic for skew values close to zero, in which case there would be no need for this function anyway.

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

def createSkewDist(mean, sd, skew, size):

    # calculate the degrees of freedom 1 required to obtain the specific skewness statistic, derived from simulations
    loglog_slope=-2.211897875506251 
    loglog_intercept=1.002555437670879 
    df2=500
    df1 = 10**(loglog_slope*np.log10(abs(skew)) + loglog_intercept)

    # sample from F distribution
    fsample = np.sort(stats.f(df1, df2).rvs(size=size))

    # adjust the variance by scaling the distance from each point to the distribution mean by a constant, derived from simulations
    k1_slope = 0.5670830069364579
    k1_intercept = -0.09239985798819927
    k2_slope = 0.5823114978219056
    k2_intercept = -0.11748300123471256

    scaling_slope = abs(skew)*k1_slope + k1_intercept
    scaling_intercept = abs(skew)*k2_slope + k2_intercept

    scale_factor = (sd - scaling_intercept)/scaling_slope    
    new_dist = (fsample - np.mean(fsample))*scale_factor + fsample

    # flip the distribution if specified skew is negative
    if skew < 0:
        new_dist = np.mean(new_dist) - new_dist

    # adjust the distribution mean to the specified value
    final_dist = new_dist + (mean - np.mean(new_dist))

    return final_dist




'''EXAMPLE'''
desired_mean = 497.68
desired_skew = -1.75
desired_sd = 77.24

final_dist = createSkewDist(mean=desired_mean, sd=desired_sd, skew=desired_skew, size=1000000)

# inspect the plots & moments, try random sample
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,7))
sns.distplot(final_dist, hist=True, ax=ax, color='green', label='generated distribution')
sns.distplot(np.random.choice(final_dist, size=100), hist=True, ax=ax, color='red', hist_kws={'alpha':.2}, label='sample n=100')
ax.legend()

print('Input mean: ', desired_mean)
print('Result mean: ', np.mean(final_dist),'\n')

print('Input SD: ', desired_sd)
print('Result SD: ', np.std(final_dist),'\n')

print('Input skew: ', desired_skew)
print('Result skew: ', stats.skew(final_dist))
```

Input mean:  497.68
    Result mean:  497.6799999999999

Input SD:  77.24
    Result SD:  71.69030764848961

Input skew:  -1.75
    Result skew:  -1.6724486459469905

[image]

Comment: This is some incredible work! Has this work been published or formally reported elsewhere? I would very much like to see how you derived this work. Thanks again for sharing.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Allow me to compile the behind-the-scenes work into a coherent narrative and I'll see about posting it somewhere for public access. So to answer the question, no I never published this or reported it elsewhere.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant piece of code. Saved me quite a few hours of sadness!

Answer (score 1):

The shape parameter of the skew-normal distribution is not the skewness of the distribution.  Check out the [wikipedia page for the skew normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution).  The formulas in the table on the right give the expressions for the mean, variance, skewness, etc.,  in terms of the parameters.  You can get these values from the `skewnorm` object with the `stats()` method.

For example, here's the skewness of the distribution with shape parameter 2:

```
In [46]: from scipy.stats import skewnorm, skew

In [47]: skewnorm.stats(2, moments='s')
Out[47]: array(0.45382556395938217)
```

Generate a couple samples and find the sample skewness:

```
In [48]: r = skewnorm.rvs(2, size=10000000)

In [49]: skew(r)
Out[49]: 0.4533209955299838

In [50]: r = skewnorm.rvs(2, size=10000000)

In [51]: skew(r)
Out[51]: 0.4536583726840712
```

Comment: I updated the question using the information you provided - thanks - but are you able to assist with the remaining part?